# Spell checker error: null cannot be parsed to a squiggly dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, air, filesystems, directory

I organized a spell-checker with help Squiggly in my app ( http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/).

```
_newdict.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadComplete);
_newdict.load("dictionaries/en_EN/en_EN.aff", "dictionaries/en_EN/en_EN.dic");
```

Everything works fine when the dictionary files is in the same folder as the app. But the dictionary have large size (over 5MB). Therefore load it on user demand. Files can not save the program folder, but only application Storage Directory.

However, when initializing the dictionary there is an error: null cannot be parsed to a squiggly dictionary. I've tried both ways: file1.nativePath and file1.url, it is still the error.

```
var file1:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dictionaries/en_EN/en_EN.aff");
var file2:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("dictionaries/en_EN/en_EN.dic");
if (!file1.exists || !file2.exists){
    //download files from the server
} else {
    _newdict.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadComplete);
    _newdict.load(file1.nativePath,file2.nativePath);
   //_newdict.load(file1.url,file2.url);
}
```

Tell me how to solve the issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

Using your code sample and the dictionary files included with Squiggly, `.nativePath` works fine. Though, I get the "null cannot be parsed" error when `dictionaryURL` is a text file in an encoding other than [ANSI (Windows-1252).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) Files can be converted fairly easily with a text editor.

Though, if you're trying to spell-check languages that use characters outside the range of that encoding, the standard loading method won't work. The only workaround I can think of is `_newDict.squigglyDictionary.addWord`, which seems to accept all characters.

I also got the error when the dictionary file was blank. So that could be the problem too.

Comment: CheeseWarlock, thank you. But nothing solved the issue. I converted the files to ANSI - the old error. And even in the UTF-8 everything works fine in the app directory. I do not use characters outside the range of that encoding, because the COMPLETE event is not even happening. Dictionaries are not blank, because the have the usual size. Probably the problem with security. I tried on the desktop and on the Android device (mobile project) - one result.